# SQL query works in MySQL but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

This SQL query:

```
String query = 
    "select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient " +
    "where userclient.userid = " + 
    "(select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where " +
    "follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = " +
    userID +
    ")";
```

Prints this on the console:

> select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where
>   userclient.userid = (select follower.followerid from
>   twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid
>   and follower.userid = 562570958)

This query works when run directly in MySQL script, but not when executed via a Java program running in Eclipse. When run in Eclipse I get this exception:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Column 'followerid' not found.
```

I already have the table Follower with the column `followerid` in it. How do I resolve this?

EDIT:
UserClient table has 2 columns: userid and username.
Follower table has 3 columns: rowno,userid and followerid.

Comment: not familiar with eclipse but you need to make sure it supports subqueries for this to work there i know mysql does support it

Comment: What columns do you have in both tables?

Comment: Add the DDL for both tables to your question please. Also, why aren't you using a JOIN instead of that sub-select?

Comment: I described the tables in the edited post above.

Comment: Are you sure that you are really using _the same_ database in both mysql and Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

```
select userclient.username 
from twitter_content.userclient as userclient 
where userclient.userid =
(select follower.followerid 
from twitter_content.follower as follower 
where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = 562570958)
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Print that query and copy it. Then try to run that query in mysql.

If it is working fine then verify the connection to database. It may be connecting to an old database that does not have 'Follower' table with 'followerid '

Answer (score -2):

looks like you put in a dot instead of a comma

```
select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where userclient.userid = (select follower.followerid from twitter_content,follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = 562570958)
```

also not sure why you have twitter_content in the subquery from clause

Comment: Nope,I use the dot to refer to a table of a particular schema.